# How do I make a Timer ActionListener wait for another one to stop before starting

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I'm trying to make a Serpents and Ladders  java application, and I wanted to animate jLabels moving. I've wanted the player to move horizontally then vertically but when I do they happen at the same time. How do I make the second timer (vertical) wait for the horizontal to stop. Here's simplified code.

```
private void mover(javax.swing.JLabel label,boolean inv,boolean y){

    ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
        int timesq = 40;
        int delta = 1;
        int deltax = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (inv){
                    delta = -1;
                }
                if (y){
                    deltax = 1;
                }
                int x = label.getX() + delta;
                int y = label.getY() + deltax;
                label.setLocation(x, y);
                label.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                repaint();
                if (--timesq <= 0){
                    Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        };
    Timer timer = new Timer(20,a);
    timer.start();

}
```

and the button that triggers the movement

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        setLayout(null);
        jLabel1.setSize(jLabel1.getPreferredSize());
        //add(jLabel1);
        //Horizontal movement
        int b = 5;
        while(b!=0){
            mover(jLabel1,false,false);
            b--;
        }
        //Vertical movement
        b = 2;
        while(b!=0){
            mover(jLabel1,false,true);
            b--;
        }


}
```

Comment: You simply need to start the second timer from the place, where you stops the first.

Comment: Yes, once you have gotten to your preferred location of your object, simply stop the first timer and start another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move at Y direction after X direction move is completed :

```
private void mover(JLabel label,boolean inv,boolean y){

    final int delta = inv ? -1 :1 , deltax =  y ? 1: 0, timesq = 40;

    ActionListener moveX = new ActionListener() {

        int counterX = timesq, counterY = timesq;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(--counterX > 0){ //move at x direction 
                int x = label.getX() + delta;
                label.setLocation(x, label.getY());
                label.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            }else if(--counterY > 0){ //move at y direction
                int y1 = label.getY() + deltax;
                label.setLocation(label.getX(), y1);
                label.setText(String.valueOf(y1));
            }else{
                Timer timer = (Timer)e.getSource();
                timer.stop();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(20,moveX);
    timer.start();
}
```

[image]

(Copy-paste-run a complete test code from [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/NqYCCIGW2d))